# SyntaxError javascript php

Tags: javascript, php

This is a heart with a wishlist, I want to add the product to my wishlist.

I have a syntax error in the console

> `Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'`

Dreamweaver shows me no errors

```
<div>
  <i id="id'. $result->id .'" 
     class="far fa-heart cart_heart" 
     onClick="add_to_wishlist("' . $result->id . '", "add")">
  </i>
</div>  

<script>
   function add_to_wishlist(id) {
      alert(id);
   }    
</script>
```

**HTML output**

```
<i id="id17254" 
   class="far fa-heart cart_heart" 
   onclick="add_to_wishlist(" 17254",="" "add")"="">
</i>
```

**php output with html** (need to ajax)

```
    if(empty(h($result->id)))
    {  }
    else 
    {
        $html .= '
            <td width="30%"><label>Heart:</label></td>  
            <td width="70%">
            
            <div>
            <i id="id'. $result->id .'" class="far fa-heart cart_heart"
            onClick="add_to_wishlist(' . $result->id . ', 'add')"></i>
            </div>  
            
            </td>  
        </tr>
        ';  
        }

    $html .= '</table></div>';

echo $html;
```

Comment: Check the resulting markup (or just have a look at the strange syntax highlighting) and you should see the problem

Comment: You are using double quotes(**"**) and single quotes (**'**) at the wrong places.  correct way is ``onClick="add_to_wishlist('" . $result->id . "', 'add')"``

Comment: @Not A Bot I tried this php syntax error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected `

Comment: @Not A Bot this is js inside php code:)

Comment: @sagittarius Inside PHP code means inside ``echo`` statement?

Comment: @Not A Bot one moment I show you.....

Comment: @Not A Bot check `php output with html` `echo` is at the end.

Comment: @sagittarius Before this statement ``$html .= '</table></div>';`` there is **}**, can you tell from where **}** is coming(For which block of code **}** is applicable)

Comment: @Not A Bot html output work's fine, I want only add `wishlist heart` check this - click `http://mantykora.cleoni.com:8080/photo_gallery/public/product_configurator.html/10082&cotton-kinkiet-1`

Comment: @Not A Bot click `cotton 300`

Comment: @sagittarius **}** is creating a problem as this is ending some block of code

Comment: @ Not A Bot this comes from if else statement, secure if no id show empty div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not having clarity over the code, it is somewhat difficult to tell the main cause of the error, as according to the error you are getting is

> `Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'`

There is a code of block that is ending with these curly braces **}**

Also, you need to escape characters to make your code work properly.

```
$r = 1; //I am assuming this for simplicity

$html ='
     <div>
        <i id="id'.  $r  .'" class="far fa-heart cart_heart"
           onClick="add_to_wishlist(\'' .  $r  . '\', \'add\')"></i>
      </div> ';  

echo $html;
```

The above code produces this **HTML** code

```
<div>
   <i id="id1" 
      class="far fa-heart cart_heart" 
      onclick="add_to_wishlist('1', 'add')">
   </i>
</div>
```

You need to escape characters(\') to work around single quotes(') that is in your PHP code.

```
 onClick="add_to_wishlist(\'' .  $r  . '\', \'add\')"
```

Here adding `\'` helps in formatting parameters correctly.